# Jquery - check/uncheck radio buttons on arent click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I have 2 radio buttons, were each button is wrapped within a div..

```
<div>
  <div class="form-radio selected">
    <input type="radio" checked/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-radio >
    <input type="radio"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to click in the div element form-radio(parent) which makes it easier for the user to click rather than the radio button, and still work as if the radio button is clicked. How can I do this with jquery?

Comment: If you plan to use it as a Radio Group, both radio buttons should have the same value for **name** attribute

Comment: Thanks for the tip! however Im using cake to generate a set of radio buttons and questions based on a db table, it ain't what I needed. Still marked as useful, since it might be, for someone else! cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)** to get the child `input` and **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** to set the checkked state of your `input`:

```
$('.form-radio').click(function() {
    $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: Just figured out that you don't really need to unset the other radio button!(Which was what I was trying to do apart from doing what you described) Thanks a heaps